# What does "not to betray too green an interest in fate" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

Can someone help by paraphrasing this sentence from Thoreau's *Walden*:

> *Think, also, of the ladies of the land weaving toilet cushions against the last day, not to betray **too green an interest in their fates**! As if you could kill time without injuring eternity.*

Comment: Likely Thoreau was using *green* in its sense of *naive*, here.

Comment: Or perhaps *lively*?  Meaning, not wanting to seem too interested?

Comment: Just tagging along here, nice to see @DanBron again after he kindly answered a Walden question yesterday :D

Answer (score 4):

Oxford has an interesting alternate definition for *green.*

> **Still strong or vigorous**: first there was **green** old age, hardly different from middle age

[See definition 3.5](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/green)

It seems like it might be synonymous with *keen*.